# Query to show tables with LOGGING turned on?

Tags: oracle11g

Is there a way to query an ORACLE database to return tables that have LOGGING turned on? or off?  I have searched the docs but cannot seem to find anywhere that answers this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_tables
 WHERE logging = 'NO'
```

will literally answer the question.  Depending on your privilege level and what set of tables you are interested in, you may want to use `all_tables` or `user_tables` rather than `dba_tables`.

Since the name `LOGGING` is somewhat misleading, though, hopefully you understand [what the `LOGGING` attribute really means](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5280714813869).  A table with `LOGGING` set to NO will still generate just as much redo log information for normal DML operations as one with `LOGGING` set to YES.  It is only when you are doing a direct path insert that redo generation can potentially be bypassed and whether that actually happens on the archivelog mode and whether force logging is set.